# SP2013 Site collection not being crawled for results

Tags: sharepoint-server, search, search-results, crawl, crawl-rules

I have a site collection on SP2013 that is not being crawled for results.

The Crawler user account is a member of the user policy on the web applications with full read permissions.

I have other web applications on the server where the search results are showing after a full crawl using the same crawler account.

Any ideas how to resolve this? Have previously tied re-creating SSA however this has not resolved the problem due to the fact that results are being shown for another site in a different WA.

Comment: Might be that everything is set up correctly and that your Search Service is healthy. Check if the site collection has a no-crawl flag by going to http://siteCollectionUrl/_layouts/15/srchvis.aspx and check if it's set to "no". Otherwise i would check the result/contentsource for any exclusions in your SSA.

Comment: Allow this site to appear in search results? is set to Yes. There doesn't appear to be any exclusions.

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot the issue, check things below:

1. Check if the site collection is crawled successfully in the crawl log.
2. Check if there are query rule and crawl rule in search service application to exclude the site collection from search result.
3. Check if “Local SharePoint Results” is used in search service application.
4. Reset index in the search service application.
5. Create a new site collection to check if the same issue will occur.